# Ruby on Rails: Best way to implement querying big amount of data

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, model-view-controller

I'm creating an application that is very heavy in data, almost like an inventory system. In index, I had to query/load a big amount of data, and inside my controller, I have this code.

```
@vehicles = Vehicle.all
```

`@vehicles` will all be listed in the corresponding view.

At first, this was not a problem because the number of vehicles was just around hundreds. But as the vehicle's number increases, the application becomes very slow.

What is the best way to implement this kind of scenario in RoR?

Comment: Rails provide something built-in - http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v2.3.11/active_record_querying.html#retrieving-multiple-objects-in-batches

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you considered pagination? Because even if the DB is fast and instandly returns your data, the view/html will be so long, that rendering will take very long

Comment: thank you for the idea. I'll start with that. I'll mark this correct if it works. I still need to do research in implementing pagination.

Comment: check out [kaminari](https://github.com/kaminari/kaminari) gem if you want a pagination

Comment: @Fallenhero, thanks for the idea. I made it work and now fully working. thanks